# Facebook post to friends

Tags: facebook, api, friend

is any way to post request to user friends without dialog , maybe trow api?

```
function post_request($fbApp, $fbID, $post)
 {
  static $ins;
 if (empty ($ins[$fbApp]))
  {
     Facebook::setConfig ($fbApp);
     $ins[$fbApp] = new Facebook(); 
  }
 try 
  {
  $res = $ins[$fbApp] -> api ('/' . $fbID . '/apprequests', 'POST', $post);
  return true;
  }
 catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
  {
  return false; 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, not anymore. Could be done long time ago, but since 2010 I think, no.

Comment: yes that ability to allow Facebook apps to spam friend accounts on their wall was correctly removed from the API by Facebook.  I remember when there was basically nothing on a user's "wall" other than spammy app messages, invites, etc.